# Complex html within bootstrap tab header element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want bootstrap to show several elements inside tab header button, currently it breaks into multiple buttons...

Consider example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zd1368yu/2/):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="allmembers">
        <a href="#allmembers" data-toggle="tab">The first</a>
        <a href="#allmembers" data-toggle="tab">tab</a>
    </li>
    <li class="additional">
        <a href="#additional" data-toggle="tab">The second</a>
        <a href="#additional" data-toggle="tab">tab</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="allmembers">
        Content
        <p> <a href="javascript: ;" id="next">next</a></p>
    </div>                    

    <div class="tab-pane" id="additional">
        Content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

In example above it would show four tabs instead of two, but I need bootstrap to be able to render complex html, something like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="all members">
        <div>
            Any type of content displayed inline here
            <a href="#allmembers" data-toggle="tab">The first</a>
            <a href="#allmembers" data-toggle="tab">tab</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="additional">
        <div>
            Any type of content displayed inline here
            <a href="#additional" data-toggle="tab">The second</a>
            <a href="#additional" data-toggle="tab">tab</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="allmembers">
        Content
        <p> <a href="javascript: ;" id="next">next</a></p>
    </div>                    

    <div class="tab-pane" id="additional">
        Content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

How can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all inline elements inside a tab header, you just need to wrap them inside an anchor, like this:

```
<a href="#additional" data-toggle="tab">
    The second <br/>
    Any type of content displayed inline here <br/>
    <span>Span</span>
</a>
```

The reason is that bootstrap style for panel header is placed on anchor, if you need more complex structures you might need to change bootstrap and place the styles on `li` instead.

your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zd1368yu/3/

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I've come out with my problem now, but it doesn't suite me well, I would need rendering two anchors or a div inside <li> element

Comment: @Lu4 for `div` I guess you can use `display: inline-block;`, for `a` you need to override bootstrap styles, or a better solution is to give a inner anchor a class and then override bootstrap styles